# What mpeg 4 settings should be used for video streaming to an iPad?

Tags: ipad, streaming

I need to encode multiple videos for CDN distribution. I have chosen to use the popular MP4 format, but I am confused by all the possible settings. What values should I use to get the best output for playback on an iPad?

iOS Specs: http://www.apple.com/iphone/specs.html (see TV and video)

Possible Settings:

Size

Video bitrate (bps)

Audio bitrate (bps)

Audio sample rate (Hz)

Video codec

Audio codec

2 pass encoding

Min. video bitrate (bps)

Max. video bitrate (bps)

De-interlacing [no/yes]

Keyframe period (frames)

Hint (for RTP streaming)

Answer (score 0):

Get handbrake. It has built in settings for this.

Comment: I appreciate Handbrake and all it does for me. I am trying to setup an automated service to do the same thing. Thanks.